# GROUP and SUM in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, select, group-by, sum, linq-to-entities

I want to select sum of all (paid) prices of an order item for each customer.
Here is SQL command:

```
SELECT c.name,SUM(oi.price * oi.count) from customer c
JOIN order o ON c.id=o.customer_id
JOIN order_item oi ON o.id=oi.order_id
JOIN bill b ON b.id=oi.bill_id
WHERE b.payment_id is NOT null
GROUP by c.name;
```

I don't know how to do this in EF.
Example result:

```
John Smith  1500,2  
Allan Babel 202,0  
Tina Crown  3500,78
```

(comma is used as decimal point..because price is decimal value)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your example result doesn't seem to match your SQL command, but i think you are looking for something like this:

```
var query = from c in context.Customers
            join o in context.Orders on c.id equals o.customer_id
            join oi in context.OrderItems on o.id equals oi.order_id
            join b in context.bill on oi.bill_id equals b.id
            where b.payment_id != null
            group oi by c.name into g
            select new
            {
              Name = g.Key,
              Sum = g.Sum(oi => oi.price * oi.count),
            }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot again. You are my saver :)    Why doesn't seem to match? SELECT c.name, SUM() -> so there will be name and some decimal.

Comment: @quin61 - No problem. The SQL command will result in two columns (Name, Sum). In your Example there seems to be 3 columns (Name, Number, Number). Unless I am misunderstanding what the comma is used for

Comment: Comma is used as decimal point. Now I see - its little confusing. I will edit that post

Comment: How would you do a LEFT JOIN on the OrderItems and then the SUM? So I would get the Customers even if they have no Orders with the Sum of 0. Simple join does INNER JOIN so if there are no orders, no customer either.